# How to save devise current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Trying to update current_user
but cant save after decrementing the counter attribute and getting validation error, minimum password length is 6 characters –

```
current_user.crawl_counter -= 1
current_user.save!
```

**Update:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :crawl_counter
  PASSWORD_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z\d]*$/
  validates :password, format: { with: PASSWORD_REGEX, :message => I18n.t('errors.messages.password_invalid') }
end
```

Comment: Could you give us some more details such as your Users controllers/models ?

Comment: Need to see how your model is set up. You can save the User (it's not locked by devise or anything), but your syntax could be well out

Comment: so what errors do you get on the user instance?

Comment: Changed to current_user.create! and getting validation error, minimum password length is 6 characters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you save a user, devise will usually check that password is correct and matches with password_confirmation. Password is obviously not stored in session object.

You could skip the validation:

```
current_user.save(validate: false)
```

Which won't check the password and save ok. This will only work if you don't want to validate the crawl counter field